# Gitignore error_log.txt

Tags: php, git, gitignore

What rules should i add to **.gitignore** to ignore all  `error_log.txt` files generated in php?

I have tried adding simply **error_log** to it, but it doesn't seem to work.

Im working on a Win7 x64 and i am new to Git.

Comment: just write one line
`*.txt` or `error_log.txt`

Comment: the file should be same directory as ignored file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ignore a file (like `error_log.txt`) in all directories of your repository, you should add the following rule to the `.gitignore` in the root folder of your repo:

```
error_log.txt
```

As said, that will ignore all files called `error_log.txt` in all directories and subdirectories of the repo.

---

Be aware, that `.gitignore` does only ignore files that are not tracked yet. If you have added and commited a `error_log.txt` already, that file will stay tracked. See [Ignore files that have already been committed to a Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/gitignore-file-not-ignoring?lq=1) for futher detail on that.